# Why is my SQL Server 2017 query returning incorrect results?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Below is some repro code for an issue I am having.

Run it in SQL SERVER 2017 you will get different (and incorrect) result compared with any other SQL SERVER version Setting the database to lower compatibility level on the sql Server 2017 instance, it works fine too.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it without changing the compatibility level?

### Actual Result

```
+--------------+--------------+----------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------+
| IsPriorAfter | IsIdealAfter | IsCurrentAfter | IsPrior | IsCurrent | IsIdeal | SecurityID | PosID |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------+
|            1 |            1 |              1 |       1 |         1 |       1 |        123 |     1 |
|            0 |            0 |              0 |       0 |         1 |       1 |        234 |     2 |
|            0 |            0 |              0 |       1 |         0 |       0 |        234 |     3 |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------+
```

### Expected Result

```
+--------------+--------------+----------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------+
| IsPriorAfter | IsIdealAfter | IsCurrentAfter | IsPrior | IsCurrent | IsIdeal | SecurityID | PosID |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------+
|            1 |            1 |              1 |       1 |         1 |       1 |        123 |     1 |
|            0 |            1 |              1 |       0 |         1 |       1 |        234 |     2 |
|            1 |            0 |              0 |       1 |         0 |       0 |        234 |     3 |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------+
```

### Repro

```
if object_id('ForSubQuery') is not null begin
    DROP TABLE ForSubQuery
end
Create Table ForSubQuery
(   
    SecID int
)

INSERT INTO ForSubQuery SELECT 123
INSERT INTO ForSubQuery SELECT 234

GO

SELECT * FROM ForSubQuery

if object_id('MainTable') is not null begin
    DROP TABLE MainTable
end
Create Table MainTable
(   
    IsPrior bit,
    IsCurrent bit,
    IsIdeal bit,
    [SecurityID] int,
    PosID int
)

INSERT INTO MainTable SELECT 1,1,1,123,1
INSERT INTO MainTable SELECT 0,1,1,234,2
INSERT INTO MainTable SELECT 1,0,0,234,3

GO

SELECT * FROM MainTable

SELECT 
       CASE
            WHEN
                Position.IsPrior = 1
                AND Position.[SecurityID] in (SELECT
                SecID
                FROM ForSubQuery
                )               
                 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS IsPriorAfter
       ,CASE
            WHEN
                Position.IsIdeal = 1
                AND [Position].[SecurityID] IN (SELECT
                        secid
                FROM ForSubQuery            
                    )
                 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS IsIdealAfter 
     ,CASE
            WHEN
                Position.IsCurrent = 1
                AND [Position].[SecurityID] IN (SELECT
                        secid
                FROM ForSubQuery
                    )
                 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS IsCurrentAfter
    , Position.*
    FROM MainTable [Position]
    order by Position.PosID
```

Comment: The problem is the same subquery exists in multiple case statement, it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Cannot reporduce it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4599ff70f67ba94c473070c368ce5b04

Comment: Please post `SELECT @@version` I suggest installing newest CU-13

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**

This is [a bug that has been fixed in CU8](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4338330) so installing at least that CU and ideally the most recent one will fix it.

**Pre SQL Server 2017**

[image]

In SQL Server 2016 the plan looks as above. The `IN` is treated the same as `EXISTS` so it evaluates the following three columns.

```
   CASE WHEN IsPrior = 1   AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ForSubQuery WHERE SecID = MainTable.SecurityID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsPriorAfter
   CASE WHEN IsIdeal = 1   AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ForSubQuery WHERE SecID = MainTable.SecurityID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsIdealAfter
   CASE WHEN IsCurrent = 1 AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ForSubQuery WHERE SecID = MainTable.SecurityID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsCurrentAfter
```

Each subquery instance gets its own operator in the plan and the query returns the correct result but this is sub optimal as the  identical subquery may be executed **up to** three times per row.

Because each sub query has an `AND` next to it SQL Server can skip evaluating the sub query if the result of that expression is false however. This is achieved by each nested loops containing a pass through predicate. For example the one corresponding to evaluation of `IsPriorAfter` has a pass through predicate of `IsFalseOrNull (IsPrior=1)`

`IsPrior=1` is a boolean expression that can return `false`, `null`, or `true`. The `IsFalseOrNull` then inverts the result and returns `1` for `false`, `null` and `0` for `true`. So the pass through predicate evaluates to `true`/`1` if `IsPrior` is anything other than `1` (including `NULL`) and would then skip executing the sub query.

**SQL Server 2017 RTM**

SQL Server 2017 introduces a new optimisation rule [`CollapseIdenticalScalarSubquery`](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-2017-scalar-subquery-simplification/). In the RTM version the execution plan is not correct.

**Problem Plan**

[image]

The sub query is now in a single operator and the pass through predicates are combined

```
IsFalseOrNull([IsCurrent]=(1)) OR IsFalseOrNull([IsIdeal]=(1)) OR IsFalseOrNull([IsPrior]=(1))
```

However this condition is not correct! It evaluates to `true` unless **all** three of `IsPrior`, `IsIdeal`, `IsCurrent` are `1`.

So in your case the sub query is only executed once (for the first row in the table - where all three of the columns are equal to 1).

For the two other rows it should be executed but isn't. The nested loops has a probe column that is set to `1` if the correlated subquery returns a row. (Labelled `Expr1016` in the plan). When execution is skipped this probe column is set to `NULL`

The final compute scalar in the plan has the following expression. When `Expr1016` is `null` this evaluates to `0` for all three of your calculated columns using `CASE`.

```
[Expr1005] = Scalar Operator(CASE WHEN [IsPrior]=(1) AND [Expr1016] THEN (1) ELSE (0) END), 
[Expr1009] = Scalar Operator(CASE WHEN [IsIdeal]=(1) AND [Expr1016] THEN (1) ELSE (0) END), 
[Expr1013] = Scalar Operator(CASE WHEN [IsCurrent]=(1) AND [Expr1016] THEN (1) ELSE (0) END)
```

**SQL Server 2017 patched**

The final fixed plan after the CU is applied has the same plan shape as the 2017 RTM plan (with the subquery only appearing once) but the pass through predicate is now

```
IsFalseOrNull([IsCurrent]=(1)) AND IsFalseOrNull([IsIdeal]=(1)) AND IsFalseOrNull([IsPrior]=(1))
```

This only evaluates to `true` if **none** of those columns have a value of `1` so the sub query is now evaluated exactly when needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail explanation.